# understanding the definition of measurable cardinal

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I have two silly (as usual) questions about measurable cardinals:

1) By definition an uncountable cardinal **k** is measurable if there exists a **k**-complete nonprincipal ultrafilter *U* on **k**. Now take exactly **k** distinct elements of this ultrafilter. Consider the intersection of all these **k**-many sets. I understand it  doesn't belong to the ultrafilter. But what happens to this intersection, it is always empty, it is non-empty, what is the cardinality of it?

2) If  **k** is the smallest measurable cardinal then 2^**k** is non-measurable by inaccessibility? If **m** is another measurable cardinal, and hence **m**>**k**, then **m**>2^**k**?

Thanks in advance.
Please let me know because these questions can be considered silly.

Comment: Addressing your last paragraph: These are totally valid questions to ask and in no way 'silly'. In general, don't be afraid to ask question only because you fear someone else may disregard them as unworthy. As long as you put sufficient effort into your posts, all of you math-related questions are welcomed here at MSE.

Comment: Dear Stefan thanks for both answers. About question 2) I had understood that measurable cardinals work this way but I couldn't belive it.

Comment: You're very welcome. Large cardinals (whether they be measurable or otherwise) truly deserve their name (-;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. There is no general answer to this. Consider these examples

   - Let $x_\xi := \kappa \setminus \xi$ for all $\xi < \kappa$. Since $U$ is nonprincipal and $\kappa$-complete, we have $x_\xi \in U$ for all $\xi < \kappa$. And clearly
     $$
     \bigcap_{\xi < \kappa} x_\xi = \kappa \setminus \big(\bigcup_{\xi < \kappa} x_\xi\big) = \kappa \setminus \kappa = \emptyset
     $$
   - Let $x \subseteq \kappa$ be bounded and let $y_\xi = x_\xi \cup x$, where $x_\xi$ is as about. Then
     $$
     \bigcap_{\xi < \kappa} y_\xi = x
     $$
     is bounded in $\kappa$ and thus not in $U$
   - Let $x_\xi = \kappa \setminus \{ (2 \odot \eta) \oplus 1 \mid \eta < \xi \}$ for all $\xi < \kappa$, where $\odot$/$\oplus$ denote ordinal multiplication/addition respectively. ($\dagger$) Then
     $$
      \{ \lambda < \kappa \mid \lambda \text{ is a limit ordinal} \} \subseteq\bigcap_{\xi < \kappa} x_{\xi}
     $$
     and since $\{ \lambda < \kappa \mid \lambda \text{ is a limit ordinal} \} \in U$ we also have $\bigcap_{\xi < \kappa} x_\xi \in U$.
2. You are correct: Let $\kappa < \mu$ both be measurable. Then, as $\mu$ is inaccessible, $2^\kappa < \mu$ and, by the same reasoning $2^{2^\kappa}< \mu$ and even
   $$
   2^{2^{\ldots^{2^\kappa}}}
   $$
   If "$\ldots$" has length $< \mu$. (More precisely, if we define a sequence $\rho_i$ by $\rho_0 := \kappa$, $\rho_{i+1} := 2^{\rho_i}$ and $\rho_{\lambda} := \sup_{i < \lambda} \rho_i$ then $\rho_i < \mu$ for all $i < \mu$.)

($\dagger$) It's almost as if I can hear Asaf typing his complaints about this notation even while I'm still writing this answer.

Answer (score 3):

(I).If $F$ is a $k$-complete  free ultra-filter on the uncountable cardinal $k$ then every member of F has cardinal $k$. Let $k=A\cup B$ where $A\cap B=\phi$ and $|A|=|B|=k.$ Exactly one of $A, B,$ say $A,$ belongs to $F.$ Then $G=\{A\cup \{b\}: b\in B\}$ is a family of members of $F$ with $|G|=k$ and $\cap G=A\in F.$  In fact $H=\{A\cup C:C\subset B\}$ is a family of members of $F$ with $|H|=2^{|B|}=2^k,$ and $\cap H=A\in F.$

On the other hand let $A\in F$ and $B'\subset F$ with $|B'|=|A\setminus B'|$. Let $I=\{A \setminus \{b\}: b\in B'\}.$ Then $I\subset F$ and $\cap I=A\setminus B'$ may or may not belong to $F$. Exactly one of $B',A\setminus B'$ belongs to $F.$

(II). A measurable cardinal $k$ is a strong limit cardinal (I do not think this is obvious): If $m<k$ then $2^m<k.$ So a power cardinal cannot be measurable. In particular $2^k$ is not measurable.

(III). BTW. A measurable cardinal is regular. And if $k$ is the least uncountable cardinal that has a countably-closed free ultrafilter $F$ then $F$ is  $k$-closed and $k$ is the least measurable cardinal.

Comment: Dear Daniel, thank you very much!